# Updating object values of different types inside function

Tags: typescript

Are there elegant ways to improve `updateWidget()` to resolve the warning in the `else` clause?

```
type Widget = {
    name: string;
    quantity: number;
    properties: Record<string,any>
}

const widget: Widget = {
    name: "value",
    quantity: 1,
    properties: {name: "property1", name: "property2"}
}

function updateWidget(key: string|number, value: string|number, property:boolean) {
    if(property) {
        widget.properties[key] = value;
    } else {
        widget[key] = value;
    }
    return widget;
}
```

Error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type 'Widget'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Widget'.(7053)

Comment: Pro tip: your questions often feature a plea for "anybody" to do some work for you. Ideally, questions are best asked in the format "how do I / how can I" do some work - it may seem like a subtle shift, but it reflects a positive-thinking attitude and a personal agency that is a good habit for engineers to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Make your function a generic so that the key and the value type can be matched :

```
function updateWidget<K extends keyof Widget>(key: K, value: Widget[K], property:boolean) {
    if(property) {
        widget.properties[key] = value;
    } else {
        widget[key] = value;
    }
    return widget;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glgEwOYWFAvFA3gKClAOwEMBbCALigGdgAnOApAbjygEcBXIg4OUSghxIAjCLRb4wtAPaRavCFUoAlCAGNptBAB4a9RgBoo3EAD4cAXxw4NBGlADuiFMErxkqDNlbEylAEQAbkQANhwQ-gasnNy8-FAAjFGSMnIKStiEpBRQ-lKyYqAJ-lBWVjgAZhwEarzSBFAcYAhEwBDuLtoA0lAQAB5tBAhUUADWECDSFbDOqKYAFOMglF1GwWE5HagA2l0Aukb5aSAA-JTC0tIhENwAlN74cNPzR4Ug97j4+E4ewAB0r3kcEU2yWey863CElKvRCVGgny+PxcoIm4MwkIg0Ks+FoqA4tAayNQLHKTRabS2wHmAHJAekaUYsFAKpdKABmUq3IA)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using function overloads together with generics so get the strict typing on the overload definitions and looser types on the implementation signature so you should still get okay type safety, but since you're not passing in the object that's getting updated as an argument you can't alter the signature for the implementation so have to cast it to something looser.

Something like this should work

```
function updateWidget<K extends keyof Widget>(
  key: K,
  value: Widget[K],
  property: false,
): Widget;
function updateWidget<K extends keyof Widget["properties"]>(
  key: K,
  value: Widget["properties"],
  property: true,
): Widget;
function updateWidget(
  key: string,
  value: unknown,
  property: boolean,
) {
  if (property) {
    widget.properties[key] = value;
  } else {
    (widget as Record<string,unknown>)[key] = value;
  }
  return widget;
}
```

but using a flag like that for resolving what properties to access might not be the simplest solution to use, and the typing gets a bit annoying.

I would go for some generic update object function, something simple like this

```
type Obj = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>;

const update =
  <T extends Obj>(obj: T) =>
  <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K] | ((current: T[K]) => T[K])) => {
    const current = obj[key];
    if (value instanceof Function) {
      return { ...obj, [key]: value(current) };
    }
    return { ...obj, [key]: value };
  };
```

that you can then call

```
const updated = update(widget)('properties',(p)=>({...p, 'any':5}))
```

and then it can work for other objects and you can call it again like

```
const next = update(widget)("properties", (p) => update(p)("field", "value"));
```

link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=46&ssc=79&pln=46&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glgEwOYWFAvFA3gKClAOwEMBbCALigGdgAnOApAbjygEcBXIg4OUSghxIAjCLRb4wtAPaRavCFUoAlCAGNptBAB4a9RgBoo3EAD4WAXxY4NBGlADuiFMErxkqDNlbEylAEQAbkQANhwQ-gasnNy8-FAAjFGSMnIKStiEpBRQ-lKyYqAJkVlkAEwB%20WkgZf5QFlFWODgAZhwEarzSBFAcYAhEwBDuLtoA0lAQAB5DBAhUUADWECDSLbDOqKYAFKzLIJRjyVDBYTkjqADaYwC6x1WFB1AtoVQQUQCUbpvALG0dXR6fQGQwuwHGkxmEDmC32aw2HmAlzyqUKcEU-huOz2K0Ox1O4W%20iORD3k6KomPuqPkTzo4U%20RJcf3anTg3V6-UGwx%20232lD0DCQRgJOXaiwI0gcBCMpPiwmk0hCEG4H28%20Dg622spAqtw%20HwTkRADpZeTLvsbl4RRJ6pMQm81frtoaXMYFqoNFpdHRBUYxRKpaYPuaVpbMNbWBZWLRUBxaD0XahLM1QJAoAB5YQAKy8Hs0OgACtTQGMVn6COLJQRzM1bPZgVyMKxtAAVSGzeYZ7M7aTZygt1XoUzNibTDuwlbwls7PlQI4nUKEqAt66WgA%20UG22zUcZjPH7q8HpmXh6PjvwdbQO9oe7QmF7WZDIBuNvVmpFUAYNG4agg8IAYiygK6qw%20pQDGwBxj0WBQEacEPkYT43JQIrbru0LAKqTRgVGYEQVBmRwUaCFQEhKGLtA2H1NYl4ciCEAIF4DZDM6PwfNsKIFGSGJGFqZ7bDBRFgEYJjAAAFoKlAAKz1B8Hw0d09gEGOTGcixiaYRxpo8ZuYBnsxEB8RxLToiECAlEEFH%20HJCl2IqEBGiE0hINsBkIPJNiKfZjnOdsykzB5QA)

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateWidget<K extends keyof Widget>(key: K, value: Widget[K], property?:false): Widget;
function updateWidget(key: string, value: string|number, property:true): Widget;
function updateWidget(key: string|number, value: string|number, property:boolean) {
    if(property) {
        widget.properties[key] = value;
    } else {
        widget[key as keyof Widget] = value;
    }
    return widget;
}
```